# Are there any x.25 protocol Java libraries?

Tags: java, protocols

I need to communicate with another machine using the x.25 protocol and Java. Are there any Java Libraries available which will help me to accomplish my goal and is it even possible doing it with Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is one. Because there is no open stack to support X.25, you don't really gain much by using Java. We can't even upgrade our OS due to X.25. We have to use HP/UX 9 because the driver for the X.25 card is not available on newer OS.

Our operations did some magic a few year ago to convert all X.25 traffic to TCP/IP using some off-the-shelf gateway. Maybe you should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in theory, although the underlying operating system would have to support it, and you'd need to integrate with its native libraries. You couldn't do it in pure java, though.